# How to fix Xperia Z3 Dual flashtool driver too old error?

Tags: rom-flashing, flashtool, sony-xperia-z3

I'm trying to install .575 firmware on my Xperia Z3 dual D6633 device with flashtool but as  i connected to the pc (with vol down pressed) flashtool says `ERROR - Device connected in flash mode but driver is too old`. How I can fix this?
I'm on latest Marshmallow update and unlocked bootloader.
[image: Screenshot of Error]

Answer (score 1):

Go to drive C and locate `C:\Flashtool\drivers`.

"flashtool" folder. Open it. Then folder "drivers", open the folder. You will see an application "flashtool drivers". Run this application as admin. Select the flash tool drivers and the fastboot drivers.

Follow the wizard by pressing next.

You must be connected to internet.